# Possible replacements to lambda to access items in an array

Tags: python

I think I saw a post the other day of a built-in function that did this:

```
def itemAt(index):
    def accessItem(item):
        return item[index]
    return accessItem
```

and it was used in stuff like maps. For example, to fetch the first element from each list in a list of lists, you could do:

```
map(itemAt(0), list_of_lists)
```

I may just be imagining things, but is there a builtin function that does something similar to that so that I can avoid the lambda syntax:

```
map(lambda x: x[0], list_of_lists)
```

As I said, this may have all been a dream, but I also "remember" seeing something like this for attributes instead of indices.

Comment: fyi using  `[ele[0] for ele in list_of_lists]`  would be a lot more efficient than using `map`.

Comment: I agree with @PadraicCunningham. Although I actually like the lambda too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), and [`operator.attrgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) for attributes.

Quoting the documentation:

> `operator.attrgetter(attr)`
>   `operator.attrgetter(*attrs)`
>
> Return a callable object that fetches *attr* from its operand. If more than one attribute is requested, returns a tuple of attributes. The attribute names can also contain dots.
>
> [...]
>
> `operator.itemgetter(item)`
>   `operator.itemgetter(*items)`
>
> Return a callable object that fetches item from its operand using the operand’s `__getitem__()` method. If multiple items are specified, returns a tuple of lookup values.